# Railsのaccepts_nested_attributes_forでdata-toggleが動作しない

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Ruby on Railsでnested_form、cocoonなどを使用して、
accepts_nested_attributes_forを使用して1対多の関係を持ったモデルを作成しています。

1対多の1の方のformで、link_to_add_associationを使用して、
動的に多のモデルの入力フォームを増減をした場合、
最初から表示されていた多のフォームのdata-toggleは正しく動作するのですが、
link_to_add_associationをクリックして増やしたフォームについてはdata-toggleが動作していません。

コードがエスケープされてしまう事に起因しているかと思うのですが、
この様な場合の対応策というのはあるのでしょうか？
そもそもlink_to_add_associationを使用した場合にdata-toggleを使うのは難しいのでしょうか？

ご教授の程、よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 0):

動的に入力フォームの増減（ajaxかと思います）した場合に、
data-toggleがロードされていないのかと思われます。

増減した際に、javascriptでdata-toggleの再ロードを行う必要があるかと思います。